# Splitting up a list into parts of balanced lengths

Tags: python, algorithm

I need an algorithm which given a list `L` and a number `N`, returns a list of `N` smaller lists where the sublists are "balanced".  Examples:

```
algo(range(1, 8), 3)  -> [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
algo(range(1, 6), 4)  -> [[1,2], [3], [4], [5]]
algo(range(1, 12), 5) -> [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [8,9], [10, 11]]
```

As you can see, the algorithm should "prefer" the first list in the output.

I've been trying for hours, but I can't figure out a nice and terse algorithm for it. This will be implemented in Python, by the way, but it's really the algorithm that I'm after here. This is *not* homework, this is for a website which will display contents in a list in three columns (Django).

---

I got the best answer from #python on freenode and it is as follows:

```
def split_up(l, n):
    q, r = divmod(len(l), n)
    def division_point(i):
        return i * q + min(i, r)
    return [l[division_point(i):division_point(i+1)] for i in range(n)]
```

Don't ask me why it works though. :)  I'll give the correct answer to the one with most votes though.

Comment: You have to sort beforehand if I'm thinking right. What is wrong with lst.sort(), then traaversing it linearly to pick off elements? It is O([the sort func]) anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320170/how-do-i-divide-an-ordered-list-of-integers-into-evenly-sized-sublists

Comment: @Corey D: that question is *slightly* different

Comment: @voyager: Adapting that algorithm to this problem in Python is a trivial exercise.

Comment: What do you mean by balanced? If you're trying to minimize the maximum sum of any sub-list, there's a an app ---- I mean, a solution for that. Will dig it up in case if such is the case.

Comment: what should `algo(list(range(1, 12)), 6)` return?

Comment: @SilentGhost: [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11]]

Comment: well, at least my answers solves the problem.

Comment: very nice solution you posted. the division_point thing is really neat. Just like my solution (in a way) it takes 1 from the rest ("r") until it is used up (i = 0, 1, 2, 3.. then i > r, min(i, r) == r).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I came up with, without the sorting. Just slap on a lst.sort() if the input is not sorted.

I think this came out nicely, using iterators and using islice to cut off the next piece.

```
import itertools

def partlst(lst, n):
    """Partition @lst in @n balanced parts, in given order"""
    parts, rest = divmod(len(lst), n)
    lstiter = iter(lst)
    for j in xrange(n):
        plen = len(lst)/n + (1 if rest > 0 else 0)
        rest -= 1
        yield list(itertools.islice(lstiter, plen))

parts =  list(partlst(range(1, 15), 5))
print len(parts)
print parts
```

Comment: This is a bout as terse as it gets.  It is a sort of tricky problem though.

Comment: it'd be an interesting code golf problem.  I'm still tinkering with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want output to contain lists of equal length when possible, otherwise give preference to lists in the beginning. Difference between lengths of sub-lists no more than one.

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> def algo(li, n):
        a, b = divmod(len(li), n)
        c = [a + 1] * b + [a] * (n-b)
        s = 0
        for i, j in enumerate(c):
            c[i] = li[s:s+j]
            s += j
        return c

>>> algo(l, 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> algo(l, 4)
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem... you would only have to add one item for each list under mod(n), where you have algo (range(a,b), n)

So you should:

1. Have b-a > n
2. Calculate b-a = n*x + y (I dont really know if the operator % exists on python, so you should get y)
3. The first y lists will have (b-a/n + 1) elements and the other lists will have (b-a/n)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tribute to functional lovers:

```
def algo(l, n):
    if n == 1: return [l]
    q, r = divmod(len(l),n)
    if r: q += 1
    return [l[:q]] + algo(l[q:], n - 1)
```

This one is a little bit smaller:

```
def algo(l, n):
    k = l[:]
    q, r = divmod(len(l),n)
    return [[k.pop(0) for _ in [0] * m]
            for m in [q + 1] * r + [q] * (n - r)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but...

```
def algo(l, n):
  return [l[-(-len(l)*i//n):-(-len(l)*(i+1)//n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Use / instead of // in older versions of Python.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if it works, then I'll be damned! :)

Comment: Those double negatives seem to be useless. I redefined it as: `[lst[len(lst) * i // n : len(lst) * (i + 1) // n] for i in range(n)]`.

Comment: @MahyarMirrashed Removing the double-negatives means the algorithm puts more items in later lists rather than earlier ones, which the OP did not want. Try it with e.g. algo([1,2,3,4], 3) to see the difference